# App Crashes whenever empty method is called

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

so i was programming a game in Xcode 3.2.4 with cocos2d and i made a class named player. as of now it only has the one function that does nothing.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Player : CCSprite {

}

-(void)leftButtonPressed;

@end 



#import "Player.h"


@implementation Player

- (id)init{
    if((self=[super init])){
        self = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"playerPlane.png"];
        }
    return self;
}

-(void)leftButtonPressed{
}

@end `
```

whenever i try to call leftButtonPressed from anywhere, the entire app crashes with this in the console

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCSprite leftButtonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e4bb50'`

i initialize the Player as an instance in another class by doing 
`Player * thePlayer = [[Player alloc]init];`

please help! thanks!!

Comment: "was programming a game in Xcode 3.2.4" … when was that, three years ago? Just kidding but seriously, even if you're still on Snow Leopard you should upgrade to at least 4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This causes the problem:

```
- (id)init{
    if((self=[super init])){
        self = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"playerPlane.png"];
        }
    return self;
}
```

What are you doing? You initialise the newly created (the caller that calls `alloc`/`init` created it)  `Player` object. The `init` method may even have returned another instance than the one that is currently executing (some strange unique cocoa thing). And when that was successful then you crate a new `CCSprite` object and assign it to `self`. `Self` is then returned to the caller. 
(If you would not ARC - I assume you do - then this for sure would create a memory leak);

But the caller expects to deal with a `Player` object and later sends the `leftButtonPressed` message to it which the `CCSprite` cannot respond to.

That is, what the error message tells you.

You may use instead:

```
- (id)initSpriteWithFile(NSString*)fileName{
    if((self=[super initSpriteWithFile:fileName])){
        // Do any additional setup here. If you don't have any setup then do not overwrit the init method at all. 
        }
    return self;
}
```

or something like:

```
- (id)init{
    if((self=[super init])){
        [self setFileName:@"playerPlane.png"]; //This method may not exist at all but you may find an appropriate one in the docs. I am not used to CCSprit. I am just trying to explain the concept by example. 
        }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `self = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"playerPlane.png"];` but this creates a `CCSprite` instance rather than a `Player` instance.

I am guessing you do not have the source of CCSprite or there isn't a non-factory based initializer?

In this case, you would be better creating a class extension rather than subclassing.